# determining the recurrence relation

Tags: recursion, big-o

I found the following code on the net, I knew that it is multiples a with b 
but I have a problem in finding the recurrence relation or determining the complexity so can you guide me

```
public int mystery(int a, int b) {
 if (b == 0) return 0;
 else if (b % 2 == 0)
  return mystery(a + a, b / 2);
 else return mystery(a + a, b / 2) + a;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation is defined by the function itself. I don't think it can differ much in math notation.

The complexity depends solely on `b` which decreases exponentially till the stop condition. Therefore the complexity will be `O(logb)`.